# Как сделать событие календаре?

Tags: java, android-intent, calendar-view

Доброго времени суток.
Есть приложение(календарь) основано на CalendarView. Как правильно сделать чтобы при нажатии на любую дату открывалось окно, куда можно записать "что-то" и сохранить. И потом при просмотре календаря было показано что на эту дату есть событие. Сделать чтобы из метода setOnDateChangeListener "вызывалась" другая активити и там записывать "что-то" или есть путь попроще?